# Gigabit Ethernet downgrading to Fast Ethernet - can it tolerate loss of any individual wire?

Tags: ethernet

I have read that a damaged cable that used to work at 1000 Mbps can still be used at 100 Mbps.  Does the specific wire inside matter?  Say, wire 1 being damaged versus wire 5 or 8?  Will two auto-negotiating ports be able to figure out which wires to use for the lower speed?

Comment: If 1-2, or 3,6 is damaged, it won't work for 10/100 either.

Comment: You should really replace a damaged cable - the price of a new cable is nothing compared to you chasing gremlins.

Comment: Thanks to both, Ricky 's example is exactly what I needed.  Zac67, the wire is in the wall and got damaged afterward, so I'll figure it out larger-scale.  To the helpful person who closed the question, the other one does not actually answer the specific question, but it's all good.